# Tomcat is running on 8080 port but unable to access remotely using ip address?

Tags: java, tomcat

[image]I have freshly installed apache-tomcat-7.0.62 on server. It starts without any error but i am unable to access it using : -

```
   http://IP:8080/
```

here IP is ip address of server.

I have also run following command : -

 here is the screenshot

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It looks like it's only listening for IPv6 connections. You can see that it isn't listening for "tcp" connections on port "8080", only for "tcp6" connections. Are you trying to access it with an IPv4 or IPv6 address?

Comment: Duplicate (sort of) of http://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address I think - please have a look!

Comment: thanks mr @mrcheshire for suggestion, but i don't know how to make it listen for tcp i.e for IPv4 address, please suggest me this too. One more thing i want to mention that i have used IPv4 address for accessing 80 port in my browser and it works for apache

Comment: @SUSHANTSRIVASTAVA did you read the question I referred to? `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` and `java.net.preferIPv4Addresses` are needed on dual stack machines where you want to use the IPV4 side of things. That's a ***Java*** thing, that doesn't affect your Apache httpd. Still more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Comment: @fvu It is listening at all addresses via both TCPv4 and TCPv6. See `tcp 0 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`.

Comment: @EJP check the edit history... Initial issue was that it didn't listen on ipv4, edit shows it now listens on ipv4 so I have no idea what this question is about anymore. Nor what OP did between screenshot 1 and screenshot 2

Comment: @EJP  I have learned topic suggested by #fvu and i made changes in configuration file and now i am able to run tomcat on tcp, but still i am not able to access it using IP address on 8080 port that's why i have posted second screen shot.

Comment: @SUSHANTSRIVASTAVA as the second screenshot shows that the server is actually listening on port 8080 of the ipv4 address, I'd have a look at firewalls & co because your hoster may block ports by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the `server.xml` located under `confs` folder of the catalina(tomcat).

Find out `Connector` tag which each one indicates for one connector isntance.

If the connector comes with no `address` attribute(as default), so tomcat will listen for all addresses. If it has `address` attribute, so just remove it out, or either have another Connector to listen for the related ipv4 address.

```
<Connector ... address="ip_v4_addr"/>
```

Check tomcat spec for Connectors [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation).

Next make sure the port is open and allowed to be invoked by any firewall, also make sure the ip-address is valid(public and reachable), and ISP doesn't block it.

Default port for tomcat(HTTP) is 8080 and 8443 for HTTPS, maybe your ISP doesn't let you workout with non-std ports, or the firewall issue.